# node.js console.log throws me undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 var sys = require("util");
```

When i try to run this code in the console, i get `undefined` as output. Even the below statement while executing throws me undefined.

```
 console.log("Hello World");
```

**Output**

```
 Hello World
 Undefined
```

> Are we going to create our own server and write code with node.js?

Comment: Please post full code you are running. There is nothing wrong with the code you showed us (except missing letters of course, i.e. `console`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last `undefined` is result returned from console.log method:

```
node
> console.log('hey')
hey
undefined
>
```

As you can see, first 'hey' printed by console.log, but console.log returns undefined as result of operation, and it printed to output.

Comment: How can i run my js files.... i created a Hello.js inside my D drive, but when i try node Hello.js i get an output .... alone

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows, but it seems your installation is broken for some reason. I suggest you to use at least cygwin. Better - virtual box with latest ubuntu to learn node. There may be lots of additional issues in windows (not node fault, it depends on many modules which may not support windows).